# Group_CONCAT CASE multiply outputs

Tags: sql, mysql, case, string-concatenation, group-concat

I have an SQL query with this line:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t3.ship=1 AND t4.item=0 THEN t2.item_name END ORDER BY item_id SEPARATOR '<br>') `My Item List`
```

Output Now: Lamp

It works perfectly, however I want to list out the item's number which is stored in item_no column.
Expected Output: 1. Lamp

I tried to add something like this, but didnt work:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t3.ship=1 AND t4.item=0 THEN t2.item_no, '.' ,t2.item_name END ORDER BY item_id SEPARATOR '<br>') `My Item List`
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Can you share an input and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate `item_no`, `'.'` and `item_name` with [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
... THEN CONCAT(t2.item_no, '.', t2.item_name) END ...
```

Comment: u r a legend brah!